# Jquery:How to use variable as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I trying to figure out how can I use a variable inside a selector. If I use the actual value of the ID in the selector, it works very well.

```
$(document).on("click",'.tag', function(){
    var data-id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if($('div[data-id="540"]').hasClass("tag_current")) {
        $('div[data-id="540"]').removeClass("tag_current").addClass("tag");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('tag tag_current');
});
```

I checked many answers and try it in different ways, but I still didn't solve it.

Comment: Is `$(this)` the same element as `$('div[data-id="540"]')`?

Comment: you can also use $(this).data("id") instead of $(this).attr("data-id")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic string concatenation:

```
$('div[data-id=' + data-id + ']')
```

Comment: I just had to also change variable for id because - is not alout.. But it worked perfectly